# Using Tweepy to Access Twitter's Premium API

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, sttwitterapi

I want to access Twitter's archive without being restricted by rate limits or number of queries. I don't mind paying for this, so my plan was to sign up for the [premium package](https://developer.twitter.com/en/pricing/search-fullarchive) on Twitter's API platform. As I'm familiar with Tweepy, I had hoped to be able to access the API in my usual way.

However, it seems that the only way I can query the API with premium credentials in Python is through the [Python Twitter Search API](https://twitterdev.github.io/search-tweets-python/), which is basically a python wrapper for the premium service. The issue is that the authentication protocols for premium access are not the same as for the rate-limited free access. This is most annoying, as the `searchtweets` library that supports the Python Twitter Search API seems fairly primitive, and I can make practically no sense of the docs.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to use Tweepy to access premium tier for Twitter? It's kinda weird that the better tools only work on the free tier.

Answer (score 8):

That is not true. You can use the same credentials (assuming you get authorized by Twitter) for both the Standard Search and the Premium Search.

The TwitterAPI python wrapper supports both -- https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)
r = api.request('tweets/search/fullarchive/:YOUR_LABEL',
                {'query':YOUR_SEARCH_TERMS})
for item in r:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks. Fair enough, seems I'm wrong on that point. My main question, though, is whether I can use Tweepy for the premium search, if my credentials allow that level of access. Any info on that?

Comment: Premium is not mentioned in the Tweepy docs, so I believe not. That is why I pointed you to TwitterAPI instead.

Answer (score 5):

Tweepy now supports the premium API as discussed [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1175). I had to install from github rather than pip. See the documentation for [API.search_30_day](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.search_30_day) and [API.search_full_archive](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#API.search_full_archive) and the [corresponding documentation for the premium search APIs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search).

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy@master
```

The `api` is different. `api.search` becomes `api.search_full_archive` or `api.search_30_day`.

```
# premium search
tweets=tp.Cursor(api.search_full_archive,environment_name='you_env_name_here', query=search_words, fromDate=date_since).items(100)

# free search
tweets=tp.Cursor(api.search, q=search_words, lang="en",since=date_since).items(100)
```

Comment: it is required to update the tweepy with `pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy@master` for using __Twiter Premium API__

Comment: Indeed, that is why I included it :) I should have made that more clear